# Meteor How to Avoid Publishing All

Tags: meteor

I thought I understood pub/sub in Meteor until I ran into this issue.

Suppose you have many blog entries that are meant for public consumption and a user navigates to /:blogId.

You use something like

```
Blogs.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam('blogId'));
```

Currently, on the server side, I'm publishing all blog entries.

```
Meteor.publish("blogs", function () {
    return Blogs.find({});
});
```

I'm guessing I should only publish the blog entries that are requested with something like:

```
Meteor.publish("blogs", function (_id) {
    return Blogs.find(_id);
});
```

What is best practice here?

Comment: Is it a package or an ordinary collection, which you created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it exactly right in your question:

```
Meteor.publish("oneBlog", function (_id) {
  return Blogs.find(_id); // must return a *cursor* or array of cursors, not an object
});

Meteor.publish("allBlogs", function () {
  return Blogs.find();
});
```

From the client subscribe to the `oneBlog` based on the route parameter:

```
Meteor.subscribe("oneBlog", FlowRouter.getParam('blogId'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make another publication (which returns only one) for specific route.

Comment: Yes, this is what I assumed.  Do you actually use findOne({})?  And do you pass it parameters in the subscription?  Can we see an example?